# how to get my app write on Sd card with Oreo

Tags: android

I have a strange problem writing on my external sd card running Android Oreo :

First the usual commands 
    getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() 
or 
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

return the path to the emulated storage not the real sd card sometimes called secondary external storage.

But well that's not the issue as I manage to get the path to the  SD card using the  method getExternalStoragePath() described at the end of my post.

Now the strange thing is that I cannot get my app (let's say the package is com.example.myapp) creating the directory

SDCARDPATH/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files

despite all necessary authorizations have been properly granted (but it is possible that the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE apply only to the emulated storage, I have a feeling that the issue is there!) Here is what I'm doing :

```
String SDCARDPATH=getExternalStoragePath(this, true);
File md = new File(new File(new File(new    File(SDCARDPATH,"Android"),"data"),PACKAGE_NAME),"files");
if(!md.exists()) {
                try {
                    md.mkdirs();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

The strange thing is that if I create the directory manually through the phone file explorer the app can then write and read within that directory without any trouble.

So my question is how to properly create that directory on my external sdcard

Side note I see some app installed on my phone have managed to create their app directory on the sd card.

Finally here is the getExternalStoragePath method I use and which was grabbed on the net :

Thanks to all in advance for your help,

Lea

```
 public static String getExternalStoragePath(Context mContext, boolean is_removable) {

    StorageManager mStorageManager = (StorageManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = null;
    try {
        storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");
        Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
        Method getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath");
        Method isRemovable = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isRemovable");
        Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);
        final int length = Array.getLength(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
            String path = (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            boolean removable = (Boolean) isRemovable.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            if (is_removable == removable) {
                return path;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have been having the same issues and things are getting worse with a Storage access framework in andorid Q

Comment: @Pemba Tamang Did you solve the issue ?

Comment: I was making an app for an individual for an arduino project I just hardcoded the path. Sorry mate

Comment: `I have a strange problem` You are using reflection. Don't be surprised to encounter 'strange problems'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I manage to get the path to the SD card using the method getExternalStoragePath() described at the end of my post

That code is not going to work on all versions of Android. In particular, it will not work on Android 10+. I would not be the least bit surprised if it fails on Android 9.0 as well, given that it relies upon reflection into system classes. It will also fail on older devices where those classes and methods do not exist.

> First the usual commands getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() or Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() return the path to the emulated storage not the real sd card sometimes called secondary external storage

Use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the `s` at the end). That returns a `File[]`. If that array has 2+ elements, all but the first element point to directories on removable storage that you can use from your app, without any permissions. The directory should already be created, but you can call `mkdirs()` on the `File` to ensure that it exists.

Comment: Thanks, that was the trick, calling getExternalFilesDirs() and examining the array result create the directory I could not create with mkdirs() :   for (File file : getExternalFilesDirs(null)) {
                if (file != null) {
                    String fpath=file.getAbsolutePath();
                    
                }
                }

Comment: How do I accept you answer ? I don't see any button for that

Comment: @Leadev: I am glad that you got it working! In terms of accepting, look for a gray checkmark to the left side of the answer -- click that to turn it green and mark the answer as accepted.