# How to get Oreo sdCard path?

Tags: android-sdcard, android-8.0-oreo, android-fileprovider, storage-access-framework

I want to delete duplicate files from SD Card. So i need to access SD Card files which give me the full path. eg. ***/storage/0C08-291C/Android/Docs/file-sample_500kB.rtf***

I got the SD Card path for all Android version greater than **SDK level 22** but not able to get SD Card access on **Android 8 Oreo** *Version 8.0* and *Version 8.1* **SDK level 26 and 27**.

I am using below method to get SD Card root path:

```
public static String getExternalStoragePath(Context mContext, boolean is_removable) {
    StorageManager mStorageManager = (StorageManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = null;
    try {
        storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");
        Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
        Method getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath");
        Method isRemovable = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isRemovable");
        Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);
        final int length = Array.getLength(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
            String path = (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            boolean removable = (Boolean) isRemovable.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            if (is_removable == removable) {
                return path;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method return ***null*** on Android Version 8 even if SD card mounted status is ***true***.

**I am checking SD Card status by using below line:**

```
boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

**And getting the SD Card path as:**

```
String externalSdCard = getExternalStoragePath(mContext, true);
```

Once i got the ***externalSdCard*** i am calling the below method to **GRANT URI PERMISSION** to **SD Card**.

```
public void takeCardUriPermission(String sdCardRootPath) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        File sdCard = new File(sdCardRootPath);
        StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        StorageVolume storageVolume = storageManager.getStorageVolume(sdCard);
        Intent intent = null;
        if (storageVolume != null) {
            intent = storageVolume.createAccessIntent(null);
        }
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To call the **takeCardUriPermission(String sdCardRootPath)** method i required **SD Card root path**. and my question is this **"How to get root path of SD Card on Android 8 Oreo"**

Comment: Could you please share the analysis of your issues done from your end i.e. code snippet, exact error so community could advice on this.

Comment: @RajPaliwal I used the method (getExternalStoragePath) from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037082/how-to-get-my-app-write-on-sd-card-with-oreo)  This method give null string response on Oreo device if i pass is_removable value to true.

Comment: Post the used code in your post. (And not in links or comments).

Comment: [@Raj Paliwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6550782/raj-paliwal)  I got this method from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037082/how-to-get-my-app-write-on-sd-card-with-oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037082/how-to-get-my-app-write-on-sd-card-with-oreo) It is working for Android version >22. but not able to get SdCard path on Android 8 Oreo.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Note: From Android Q on this method is deprecated.

Comment: And on no Android version that will give a path to a removable micro SD card. Never has done.

Comment: [@blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps) Once check my above method in answer. It works well for all android version >22 but not working for Android 8 Oreo.

Answer (score -1):

[@blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps) Below is my code to get the sd card root path.

**Activity:**

String externalSdCard = getExternalStoragePath(mContext, true);
... here *externalSdCard*, i am getting null for **Android 8 Oreo SDK level 26 and 27**. Other **SDK level >=22** working well.

**Method:**

```
public static String getExternalStoragePath(Context mContext, boolean is_removable) {
    StorageManager mStorageManager = (StorageManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = null;
    try {
        storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");
        Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
        Method getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath");
        Method isRemovable = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isRemovable");
        Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);
        final int length = Array.getLength(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
            String path = (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            boolean removable = (Boolean) isRemovable.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            if (is_removable == removable) {
                return path;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```